# Finding a matrix with conditions on $A^{-1}$ and $\det(A)=0.5$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Find matrix $A$ (without guessing) if $A^{-1}$ $2^{\mkern1mu\text{nd}}$ column is\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}
>
> And $\det(A) = 0.5$

**Attempt -**

I could make a progress knowing that $\det(A^{-1}) = 2$ obviously.

I could also notify that if $A = $

\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{pmatrix}

**Then -** \begin{pmatrix} 2a_1 + a_2 - a_3 = 0  \\ 2b_1 +b_2 -b_3 = 1 \\2c_1 +c_2 -c_3 = 0\end{pmatrix}

I don't know how to procced, Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}2&2&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&\!-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Using the above, now you find $\;A\;$. How did I do the above? Knowing the determinant of $\;A^{-1}\;$ is $\;2\;$ and just adding zeros wherever possible.

Comment: That is true, and apart from guessing the answer (which was cleaver) could i find an algorithm to find such matrix ?

Comment: @YarivLevy Just the horrible, boring and annoying way you began to show in your question. Much better adding zeros as to get an easily calculable determinant for a $\;3\times3\;$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed like this $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a & 2 & d\\ b & 1 & e \\ c & -1 & f\end{pmatrix}$

The only additional constraint we have is $\det(A^{-1})=af+ae-bd-2bf+2ce-cd=2$

Since we are required to find an instance of $A$ that works and not all possible matrices, then just select some values of $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ that fit nicely.

For instance

- let start with $a=0$, it remains $-bd-2bf+2ce-cd=2$
- let choose $b=0$, it remains $2ce-cd=2$
- a trivial choice is then $d=0,f=0,c=e=1$

And we get $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

But I could have started

- let choose $f=0$, it remains $ae-bd+2ce-cd=2$
- continue with $e=0$, it remains $-bd-cd=2$
- a trivial choice could then be $d=1,b=0,c=-2,a=0$

And we get $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

But you can as well set five of the six variables arbitrarily

- set $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5$, it remains $-3f+15=2$
- $f=3/13$ is forced.

And we get $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4\\ 2 & 1 & 5 \\ 3 & -1 & \frac 3{13}\end{pmatrix}$

It is just up to you to select whichever numbers you desire, until at some point, the equation relative to $\det(A^{-1})=2$ constrains the remaining last free variable.

Answer (score 1):

You want that $A^{-1}=[x\ y\ z]$, where $y$ is your given column, and $\det(A^{-1})=2$.

Start completing $y$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$; call $x$ and $z'$ the vectors you get. Now, set $d=\det[x\ y\ z']$ and set
$$
z=\frac{2}{d}z'
$$
Then you're done by taking $A=[x\ y\ z]^{-1}$.

In order to complete the basis, you can find the orthogonal complement, which is the null space of $[2\ 1\ {-1}]$, which is easily seen to have a basis consisting of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=-6
$$
With the above recipe,
$$
A^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & -2/3 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/6 & 2/3 &  1/3 \\
 1/6 & 1/3 & -1/3 \\
-1/2 & -1  & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
No guessing here.

Note that any other completion of $y$ to a basis will give another matrix (and you can choose how to normalize the determinant in various other ways).

This method can be easily generalized to *any* set of given columns of $A$ (of any size).